# Get last 36 hrs timestamp in javascript & compare it with php timestamp

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, date, datetime

I have a grid in which each row has a PHP format('Y-m-d H:i:s') date displayed.I wanted to apply a javascript filter which will show only those rows which has timestamp past 36hrs.

Whats the best way to first get past 36hrs timestamp & then compare that timestamp with displayed PHP timestamp using javascript.

Till now I tried using below code to get past 36 timestamp

```
var mydate=new Date();
mydate.setHours(mydate.getHours()-36);
dateInPhpFormat=mydate.getFullYear()+'-'+mydate.getMonth()+'-  '+mydate.getDate()+" 
"+mydate.getHours()+":"+mydate.getMinutes()+":"+mydate.getSeconds();
```

When I print dateInPhpFormat it shows wrong date.
Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Saying it shows the wrong date is a little vague. Can you post the output of what you have now versus what you want?

Comment: Use `moment.js` http://momentjs.com/

Comment: PHP uses seconds, JS uses milliseconds. You can't directly use a timestamp from either language in the other without doing some adjusting.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that could be wrong is that Javascript gives you the month, day, minues and seconds without leading zero. Also months are zero based, so you need to add 1 to the month.

For example month In JS: 3, in PHP(with 'm'): 03

You can add this leading zero yourself, like this;

```
var mydate=new Date();
mydate.setHours(mydate.getHours()-36);

var month = ('0' + (mydate.getMonth() + 1)).substr(-2);
var day = ('0' + mydate.getDate()).substr(-2);
var hour = ('0' + mydate.getHours()).substr(-2);
var minute = ('0' + mydate.getMinutes()).substr(-2);
var second = ('0' + mydate.getSeconds()).substr(-2);

dateInPhpFormat = mydate.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second;
```

This will give you a date string which is identical to php `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Date objects use zero based months for some reason.  Try adding `1` to the month.

```
dateInPhpFormat = mydate.getFullYear() + '-' + (mydate.getMonth() + 1 ) +'-'+mydate.getDate() + " " + mydate.getHours() + ":" + mydate.getMinutes() + ":" + mydate.getSeconds();
```